# How to troubleshoot Error: (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r

Why this line of code works fine,

```
phap        = mymont$QMEAN_ATM_RSHORT_PY > phap.min | iint.photo == 0
phap.lparconow     = mean(mymont$QMEAN_PAR_L_CO     [phap])
```

While this throws an error?

```
phap.lparconow     = rowMeans(mymont$QMEAN_PAR_L_CO     [,phap])
```

I have read other similar questions but they are quite complex and i would like to know a more general method to troubleshoot this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks really suspicious:

```
mymont$QMEAN_PAR_L_CO[,phap]
```

If `mymont` is a data frame, then `mymont$QMEAN_PAR_L_CO` is a vector, then how can you subset a vector by `[, phap]`? Do you really mean `mymont[phap, "QMEAN_PAR_L_CO"]`?

Also, when you use `rowMeans()`, `rowSums()`, `colMeans()` and `colSums`, you have to take care of possible dimension loss when subsetting. These functions take matrix like object with dimensions. [R FAQ: 7.5 Why do my matrices lose dimensions?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-my-matrices-lose-dimensions_003f) has well accounted such issue. And there are lots of similar question on stack overflow. For robustness, add `drop = FALSE` inside `[ , ]`.

Comment: thanks for your input, QMEAN_PAR_L_CO is a matrix of 34x34, and this not being my code it's a bit hard to tell what is doing. mymont is a hdf5 object so yes it can be considered a dataframe and it contains both matrices and vectors but in this case it's a matrix, and phap is also a matrix.

Comment: Actually your example helped me because I was able to run the command, unfortunately later I run into a problem related with the result of this operation, I don't think it's possible to make a reproducible example easily as this is not my code and I don't understand what's happening. thanks anyway

Comment: yes I added drop = FALSE and also changed the position of the index [phap, , drop =FALSE], but I don't know if this was the correct solution